# SSIS Data Flow Task indicates it wrote x rows, and reported no errors, but none of the rows appear in destination

Tags: sql-server, ssis

This package had worked in the past but, for whatever reason, hasn't been working as intended recently. The package has a script task that sets a file path variable to the file path for the most recent csv file in a folder and then uses this file path variable in a ConnectionString expression used in the flat file connection. There is a little "massaging" done with the csv file, skipping top x rows (file header info), specifying the delimeter, text qualifier, etc. If I use a hard coded CSV file path and preview, all looks as expected. The flat file connection is specified as the source in the Data Flow Task and a SQL table is specified as the destination. I run the package in VS, and nothing errors. VS reports "Information: 0x4004300B at MyDataFlowTask, SSIS.Pipeline: "Destination - MySQLServer Table" wrote 871 rows." but when I go query the table, none of the rows are there. What might I be missing?

Comment: It wrote 871 rows *somewhere*. Verify where the destination connection manager is pointing to along with the actual table name (someone can be clever and dynamically set these values). An even more clever person could have SSIS Transactions involved which could result in the rows being written and then rolled back but there's not enough information to go on at this point. Pictures of packages and data flows are generally helpful

Comment: I agree that would seem the case, but I never did find data actually being written anywhere. I created a new table in the same database and the data was written there as expected. I tried renaming the offending table (it had spaces in the table name) and still had issue. I dumped the data from the offending table to the new table, removed the offending table and renamed the new table equal to the offending table name and it worked fine. No constraints or triggers on the offending table, didn't end up modifying the SSIS package. Just "changed out" the offending table and it worked as expected.